# Setting up Performance Index for Optimal Control

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-calculus, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm trying to determine the performance index for the system $$\dot{\bf x} = UA{\bf x},$$ where I want to minimize the velocity of the dynamical system where each agent in the system comes to a predetermined consensus at time $T$. (Here, ${\bf x}$ is the position vector, $U$ is a control matrix, and $A$ is a constant matrix). Things I know for certain: both the initial and final velocities of the system are $\bf 0$. I set up and wanted to try to minimize the performance index: $$J = \int_0^T\left[{1\over2}\|\dot{\bf x}\|^2 - \lambda^T(UA{\bf x} - \dot {\bf x})\right]\,dt$$I'm trying to take the derivative of $$H = {1\over2}\|\dot{\bf x}\|^2 - \lambda^TUA{\bf x}$$ with respect to the vector ${\bf x}$.

Here's what I did so far:

$$\begin{align*}{\partial H\over\partial {\bf x}} &= {1\over2}{\partial\over\partial {\bf x}}(\dot {\bf x}\cdot\dot{\bf x}) - {\partial\over\partial{\bf x}}(\lambda^TUA{\bf x})\\ &= {1\over2}(\dot{\bf x}\cdot\ddot{\bf x} + \ddot{\bf x}\cdot\dot{\bf x}) - {\partial\over\partial{\bf x}}(\lambda^TUA{\bf x})\\ &= {1\over2}(2\dot{\bf x}^T\ddot{\bf x}) - {\partial\over\partial{\bf x}}(\lambda^TUA{\bf x}) \\ &= \underbrace{\dot{\bf x}^T\ddot{\bf x}}_\text{scalar} - \underbrace{{\partial\over\partial{\bf x}}(\lambda^TUA{\bf x})}_{????}\end{align*}$$

I'm not entirely sure that this is even possible. According to an [online matrix calculator](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/), the 2nd part $${\partial\over\partial{\bf x}}(\lambda^TUA{\bf x}) = A^TU^T\lambda,$$ which is an $n\times 1$ vector. Is this correct? If so, the performance index is impossible, and likely indicates my performance index is not set up correctly, but I'm not sure what might be wrong.

---

---

---

Comment: Is there a dependence of $U$ on the actual position, or on position and velocity?

Comment: What is your control input?

Comment: @LutzL I made some poor notation choices in the OP, so ignore the OP notation temporarily... My system is of the form $$\begin{align*}\dot x_i &= u_i(t)\\ &= b_i\sum_{j\in\mathcal{N}_i}w_{ij}(x_j(t) - x_i(t)).\end{align*}$$ where the control of $x_i(t)$ is given by $u_i(t)$ and is dependent on position differences $x_j(t) - x_i(t), w_{ij}$, and $b_i$. $w_{ij}$ are known. We can write the system as $$\dot{\bf x}(t) = BA{\bf x}(t),$$ where $B$ is a diagonal matrix containing the $b_i$. The $b_i$ are chosen to place the eigenvalues of $BA$ in $\mathbb C^-$. $A$ is known at the start; we need $B$.

Comment: Ran out of space, but I should mention that I can find a $B$ that *works*. However, I wanted to find an optimal $B$ that minimizes the velocity of the system. @Arash, I can't tag you in the above comment because it only lets me tag one person at a time.

Comment: Are the $w_{ij}$ non-linear functions or just coefficients in a linear function? If the former, then you are describing two problems, optimizing the "true" system and solving a linear algebra problem that might be a part of the solution of the non-linear problem.

Comment: @LutzL, the $w_{ij}$ are user-defined weights designed to scale and rotate the $x_i(t)-x_j(t)$. In each control, all but one of them are chosen arbitrarily (randomly in essence), where the remaining one is a linear combination of the other weights in the same control. Hence, I presume that they are just coefficients.

Comment: From your comment to @LutzL I suppose you want to reach some arbitrary final consensus point where $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j$. Maybe you should include this in your post or else the $U=0$ is the trivial answer.

Comment: @RTJ, indeed I do want the system to come to a consensus, but not quite all at the same point. I am doing formation control, so I want all the agents to end up in a particular shape at time $T$. However, the weights $w_{ij}$ are what determine this. Does this affect how I approach the problem significantly?

Comment: The final condition is crucial for the solution of the optimal control problem. Also, is the final time fixed or is it free? From what I understand, matrix $A$ is a Laplacian-type matrix. Does it have constant elements? Are the diagonal elements of $U$ bounded?Maybe I can help if you add a few more details in your question.

Comment: @RTJ I updated the question with more context towards the bottom. I've hidden the more irrelevant parts. Let me know what your thoughts are here.

Answer (score 1):

You get as variation of the action integral
\begin{align}
\delta J&=\int_0^T\left[\dot {\bf x}^\topδ\dot {\bf x}-δλ^\top(UA{\bf x}-\dot {\bf x})-λ^\top(UAδ{\bf x}-δ\dot {\bf x})\right]\,dt
\\
&=\left[(\dot {\bf x}+λ)^\topδ{\bf x}\right]_0^T
+\int_0^T\left[-(\ddot {\bf x}+\dot λ+A^\top U^\topλ)^\top δ{\bf x}-δλ^\top(UA{\bf x}-\dot {\bf x})\right]\,dt
\end{align}
so that the differential equations for the optimal/saddle-point solution inside the interval are
\begin{align}
\dot {\bf x}&=UA{\bf x}\\
0&=\ddot {\bf x}+\dot λ+A^\top U^\topλ
\end{align}
where the second can be reduced with the first so that $\dot λ$ is the leading derivative.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the implications of this: Using the 1st equation to reduce the 2nd, $$\dot{\lambda} = -A^\top U^\top\lambda - UAUAx.$$ For $J$ minimized, we need $\delta J = 0$, which I know $\|\dot{\bf x}(T)\| = 0$ (I want the system to come to rest at time $T$). Hence $\lambda(T) = \dot{\bf x}(T) = 0$, but we need $\lambda(0) = \dot{\bf x}(0) \ne 0$ if we want $U\ne O$. $$\dot\lambda(T) = - A^\top U^\top\lambda(T)-O\quad\implies\quad\dot\lambda(T) = \vec{c}_T.$$ $A$ is known singular, $U$ is nonsingular. Since we want to find $D$, can we even solve for $\lambda(t)$?

Comment: Ran out of space, but $U$ is known to be diagonal and invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found for the second term is correct

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\lambda^\top U\,A\,x\right) = \left(\lambda^\top U\,A\right)^\top.
$$

Sometimes the convention is used that partial derivative of a scalar with respect to a column vector gives a row vector. But if you consistently use one convention then it should not give mismatching dimensions.

However the solution for the first term is incorrect. Namely you calculated the derivative with respect to time instead of $x$. If you instead do take the partial derivative with respect to $x$, using that

$$
\dot{x} = U\,A\,x
$$

then the following expression can be obtained

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\dot{x}^\top\,\dot{x}\right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(x^\top\,A^\top\,U^\top\,U\,A\,x\right) \\
&= 2\,A^\top\,U^\top\,U\,A\,x
\end{align}
$$

And the dimensions of this expression does match the dimensions of the first partial derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Using the symbol ${\dot x}$ for the velocity has led you astray, let me use $v$ instead. I'll also use a colon as an easy way to type the scalar/inner product, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the function of interest in these new terms, and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 H &= \frac{1}{2}v:v - \lambda:v\cr
dH &= v:dv - \lambda:dv \cr
  &= (v - \lambda):dv \cr
  &= (v - \lambda):UA\,dx \cr
  &= A^TU^T(v - \lambda):dx \cr
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}  &= A^TU^T(v - \lambda) \cr
}$$
The resulting gradient has the shape of a (column) vector.